# Vishnu as a Brahmin guru

Tags: vishnu, avatars, guru

Other than Parashurama and maybe Vamana is there any full incarnation of Vishnu who is a guru or guru-like form? This can be a rare form not known.

Comment: There's Dattātreya, Kapila, Nara-Nārāyaṇa, Nārada, and Kṛṣṇa Dvaipāyana Vyāsa. All of these are Brāhmaṇas and Viṣṇu's avatāras.

Comment: @Bingming according to gita verse yada yada hi..... It means shri Hari comes to destroy wicked and save good people every yug. But if sages like kapil, vyasa are considered. I don't remember they don't destroy any wicked people. So why was the need for those avtars?

Comment: @Hope Īśvara doesn't *require* a reason to take avatāra. Also, it's not necessary that every avatāra should destroy asuras, rākṣasas and work for dharmasaṁsthāpanā via saṁhāra, like the case of Paraśurāma, Rāma, etc. Not all avatāras, are like that.  Furthermore, Vyāsa, Kapila, Dattātreya, etc. each did play important roles, in their own way. None of them, upheld the āsura-mata, or adharma. 
They were Brahmaniṣṭha śiṣṭas.

Comment: @Bingming thank you :)

Comment: @Bingming is Kapila a full incarnation?

Comment: As per Garga saṁhitā (1.1.17), Kapila is kalāvatāra, not a pūrṇāvatāra.
https://archive.org/details/garga-samhita-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n15/mode/2up?view=theater 
Paraśurāma is also not a pūrṇāvatāra, but an āveṣāvatara.